# Why doesn't this CSV parsing Node Lambda log anything?

Tags: node.js, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, fast-csv

Runtime env is Node 14 (AWS Lambda function). 
The S3 bucket and Lambda function are in the same region, and the I have confirmed that the Lambda function is able to get the object from S3 (i.e. permissions does not *seem* to be an issue). 
The Lambda triggers upon PUT of an object (a very simple CSV file) into the S3 bucket. No errors or exceptions appear in the CloudWatch log stream. 
package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@fast-csv/parse": "4.3.6"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3  = new aws.S3({region: 'us-east-2'});
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('@fast-csv/parse');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
    };
    
    const file = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
    fs.createReadStream(file.Body).pipe(csv.parse())
      .on('error', (error) => console.error(error))
      .on('data', (row) => console.log(row))
      .on('end', (rowCount) => console.log(`Parsed ${rowCount} rows`));
};
```

I also tried the following variation, which had the same outcome: 
index.js (variant)

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3  = new aws.S3({region: 'us-east-2'});
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('fast-csv');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
    };
    
    const file = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(file.Body);

    csv.parseStream(stream)
      .on('data', (data) => {
        console.info('Data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
      })
      .on('data-invalid', (data) => {
        console.error('Invalid batch row ' + data);
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        console.info('End of Stream');
      })
      .on('error', (error) => {
        let message = "Error in csv stream processing";
        console.error(message, ":", error);
      }
    );
};
```

Note: I already tried simply doing `await s3.getObject(params).createReadStream()`, but that results in `undefined` whereas getting the object via `promise()` first gets the object data.

I've been wrestling with this for hours, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hello! Have you imported fast-csv as a layer in the lambda?

Comment: @Amo, Hi! No, I haven't. I am uploading then entire directory to Lambda from my IDE when deploying, though, which includes the "node_modules" directory containing fast-csv. Do you think this would still matter?

Comment: Well if it is in the lambda's directory it should work. It's just a best practice to put external librairies in layers so that you can easily import it in other lambdas